# True of false: $N = p_1p_2\cdots p_k+1$ is prime for every positive integer $k$, where $p_1,p_2,\ldots ,p_k$ are the $k$ smallest prime numbers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We know primes are either of the form 4k+1 or 4k+3.

The products of 2 numbers of the form (4k+1) or (4k+3) is of the form 4k+1

The product of 2 numbers of the form (4k+1) and (4k+3) is of the form 4k+3

So case 1:

N = (4k+1) +1
= 4k + 2
= 2(k+1)

This is obviously not prime

Case 2:

N= (4k+3) +1
= 4k+4
= 4(k+1)

This is also obviously not prime.

So the question is false.

Is this correct? Why did the question include the fact that p1, p2, . . . , pk are the k smallest primes?

Comment: Actually, your proof is wrong, since the _smallest_ primes are not of the given form. See $N = 2\cdot 3\cdot \ldots p_k + 1$

Comment: In case 1, you have written "$(4k+1)+1=4k$". You cannot really believe they are equal, can you?

Comment: Why the down voting? The fact that his proof is wrong doesn't mean we should down vote it?

Comment: The first 6 primes are 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13 and yet $2*3*5*7*11*13 + 1= 59\times 509$, so the result cannot be true.

Comment: False.  All Euclid needed was a new prime.  What he actually gets is a new prime *factor*.  I also once expected $p_1\cdots p_k+1$ to be prime.

Comment: @hawaiianearringgroup Are you aware you're commenting on a question that's over 9 years old?

Comment: I wasn't.   Why,  is it a problem?  @RobertIsrael. Euclid's proof is over $2,000$ years old.   So it's all relative...

Comment: @hawaiianearringgroup When making a comment, I (at least) imagine I'm having a conversation with the OP or other commenters. In this case the OP is unlikely to still be listening or interested in the topic.  Apparently his last MSE activity was more than 4 years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
(2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13)+1 = 59\cdot509,
$$
so
$(p_1\cdots p_k)+ 1$ is composite when $k=6$.

The question seems rather confused: the $k$th prime number is *not* of the form $4k+1$ or $4k+3$, but rather is $4\ell+1$ or $4\ell+3$ for some number $\ell$ that is different from $k$.  Or if you like, the $n$th (rather than $k$th) prime is of the form $4k+1$ or $4k+3$ where $k$ differs from $n$.

Then you seem to be trying to consider $p_k+1$ instead of $p_1\cdots p_k+1$.

Comment: Also, $(2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7)-1=11\cdot19$.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this http://primes.utm.edu/notes/proofs/infinite/euclids.html  It tells you  that what you think is a common mistake.

Answer (score -2):

As the question says that they are smallest prime numbers $p_1=2$ , the statement that primes are of form $4k+1$ or $4k+3$ works only for odd primes. I think the correction goes this way the first case is $2(4k+1)+1=8k+3$ and the second case is $2(4k+3)+1=8k+7$. These can't be told to be prime or composite directly. This was the mistake. To disprove it the product of primes till $13 $ can be taken.